# Unable to send mail from php

Tags: php

We are trying to send mail from a PHP program on bigrock , mail server is on Digital Ocean 
But mails are not getting sent 
Would there be any thing wrong with the way the mail server is specified ?

```
<?php
require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true); // Passing true enables     
exceptions
try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.mandify.in'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'ABC@mandify.in'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'XYZ'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'STARTTLS'; // Enable TLS encryption, ssl also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to
//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('ABC@mandify.in', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('QWERTY@gmail.com', 'Joe User'); // Add a recipient
//Content
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Same Code was also run for mail server on bigrock (same server as execution) 
but that too did not work

This is the error message:

> Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

There seems to be something wrong with the code as per feedback from server admin team.

Comment: I thinks its pretty clear that your SSL certificate has been rejected. Either use a correct certificate or don't use SSL at all, if its an internal connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a configuration problem or an indication of a missing dependency. One thing to try to avoid failure of certificate verification is to configure the following:

```
'ssl' => [
  'allow_self_signed' => true,
  'verify_peer' => false,
  'verify_peer_name' => false,
]
```